# Are there legal reasons why dynamic DNS services are not anonymous?

Tags: legal, free, dynamic-dns

I'm looking for a dynamic DNS service that is both free and anonymous, but I've been unable to find one that is anonymous.

All the services I've found that are free require a user sign up and registration, where you have to provide an email address.

I was wondering if there are legal reasons for this?

Would a dynamic DNS service loose their domain names if they gave away sub-domains anonymously?

Comment: One word. Liability. There are things people can do on the web that jeopardizes the ability for a site owner to operate. For example, copyright violations, defamation, slander, etc. Not to mention, giving access to my own site and severs with knowing who you are would seem foolish at best reckless otherwise.

Comment: An email address is hardly validation of who you are.   Just sign up for a free email address first that you use only for this purpose.